# Scraping names of directors from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping the names of the directors from a website using Python / ScraPy.  I am very new to coding (under a year and after work) - any views would be appreciated.

The reason I have a `for` loop with count from 0 to 100 is that not all the names on the website have a date of birth, and hence where there are blanks I need to return a value ("n/a" in this case) otherwise the lists of names / namerefs / roles / dateofbirths will get out of order.

```
import scrapy
import re

from CompaniesHouse.items import CompanieshouseItem

class CompaniesHouseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "companieshouse"
    allowed_domains = ["companieshouse.gov.uk"]
    start_urls = ["https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/OC361003/officers",
]


    def parse(self, response):
        for count in range(0,100):
            for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="content-container"]'):
                companys = sel.xpath('//*[@id="company-name"]/text()').extract()
                companys = [company.strip() for company in companys]
                string1 = "officer-name-" + str(count)
                names = sel.xpath('//*[@id="%s"]/a/text()' %string1).extract()
                names = [name.strip() for name in names]
                namerefs = sel.xpath('//*[@id="%s"]/a/@href' %string1).re(r'(?<=/officers/).*?(?=/appointments)')
                namerefs = [nameref.strip() for nameref in namerefs]
                string2 = "officer-role-" + str(count)
                roles = sel.xpath('//*[@id="%s"]/text()' %string2).extract()
                roles = [role.strip() for role in roles]
                string3 = "officer-date-of-birth-" + str(count)
                if sel.xpath('//*[@id="%s"]/text()' %string3):
                    dateofbirths = sel.xpath('//*[@id="%s"]/text()' %string3).extract()
                else:
                    dateofbirths = ["n/a"]
                dateofbirths = [dateofbirth.strip() for dateofbirth in dateofbirths]
                result = zip(companys, names, namerefs, roles, dateofbirths)
                for company, name, nameref, role, dateofbirth in result:
                   item = CompanieshouseItem()
                   item['company'] = company
                   item['name'] = name
                   item['nameref'] = "'" + nameref
                   item['role'] = role
                   item['dateofbirth'] = dateofbirth               
                   yield item

        next_page = response.xpath('//*[@class="pager"]/li/a[@class="page"][contains(., "Next")]/@href').extract()
        if next_page:
            next_href = next_page[0]
            next_page_url = "https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk" + next_href
            request = scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url)
            yield request
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### DRY

Reduce duplicated logic using helper functions.
Currently you have 2 lines of code for each field you extract,
for example:

> ```
> companys = sel.xpath('//*[@id="company-name"]/text()').extract()
> companys = [company.strip() for company in companys]
>
> names = sel.xpath('//*[@id="%s"]/a/text()' % string1).extract()
> names = [name.strip() for name in names]
> ```

This is tedious. You could capture the common logic in a helper function, for example:

```
def to_list(xpath):
    return [v.strip() for v in xpath.extract()]
```

With that, much of the code can be simplified:

```
companys = to_list(sel.xpath('//*[@id="company-name"]/text()'))
names = to_list(sel.xpath('//*[@id="%s"]/a/text()' % string1).extract())
```

#### Repeated operations

Here, an xpath lookup is performed twice:

> ```
> if sel.xpath('//*[@id="%s"]/text()' % string3):
>     dateofbirths = sel.xpath('//*[@id="%s"]/text()' % string3).extract()
> else:
>     dateofbirths = ["n/a"]
> dateofbirths = [dateofbirth.strip() for dateofbirth in dateofbirths]
> ```

It would be better to avoid that:

```
dateofbirths = to_list(sel.xpath('//*[@id="%s"]/text()' % string3))
if not dateofbirths:
    dateofbirths = ["n/a"]
```

#### Use `"...".format(...)`

The `"%s" % ...` style formatting is old, it's recommended to use the `format` function instead, for example:

```
names = sel.xpath('//*[@id="{}"]/a/text()'.format(string1)).extract()
```

#### Formatting

Python has a style guide called [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), I suggest to follow it.

Comment: Regarding the `yield`statements: the code posted by the OP is a web spider built using the [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org) framework. Callback methods in scrapy can generate both requests and data items. Scrapy engine is the one who will consume those items. If the object is a request, the engine sends it to scrapy's scheduler. If it's a data item, the engine sends it to the item pipelines. Reference: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html

Comment: Thanks @ValdirStummJunior, I suspected that there was a good explanation for this, thanks for the enlightenment :-)

Comment: Thanks @Janos - I learned a lot from all that and have implemented it all.